# Best scenario for replication type

Tags: sql-server-2012, replication

We are using SQL Server 2012 and we have the Main office server. All modification on the product pricing table is done through the Main office.

We have 10 remote sales branches. Those remotes branches need to be updated by the products prices from the main office (read-only data, not changed by the branches). Each branch has an unique code to be identified.

All the sales process performed by the remote branches only. We need all the sales invoice tables (header & details) in the branches to be sent to the main office for consolidation and other activities.

In summary we need to send items table to the 10 remote branches and receive from the remote branches two tables (`salesHeader` and `salesDetails` tables).

Which replication type is good for our situation?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds easy. You need transactional replication for read only pricing data and merge for salesHeader and salesDetails.